# Making a simple for loop with decimals

Tags: php, loops, decimal

```
for ($x = 0.01; 
$x <= 0.99; 
$x++) {?>

<option value="<?php echo $x;?>"><?php echo $x;?></option>
   <?php
  } ?>
```

This does not work.

I am trying to get a decimal loop from .01 to .99
The amount of time I have spent on this I could have just typed it out manually :)

Comment: just loop from 1 to 99, then divide by 100 inside the loop

Comment: check answer below, beside this method, those answers are very valid

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just have to change this:

```
$x++  //Increments the value by 1
```

to this:

```
$x = $x + 0.01 //Increments the value by 0.01
```

Comment: Thanks...that did it...it goes 0.08, 0.09, 0.1, 0.11, 0.12 and so on. Can I change the 0.1 to 0.10 ?

Comment: @user3005687 What do you mean with: `0.98, 0.99, 0.1, 0.11 and so on. Can I change` i don't get that

Comment: @user3005687 Ah, jeah for sure this is just a formatting thing. So change your echo statement from: `echo $x;` -> `echo sprintf("%.2f", $x);`

Comment: @user3005687 You're welcome! (Enjoy the super bowl if you watch it :D)

Answer (score 1):

Initially, `x = 0.01`.
While incrementing (`x++`), `x = 1.01`.

So your condition fails second time, since 1.01 is greater than 0.99.

Hope you can figure it on your own on how to fix.

Comment: Thanks...got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code this way,

```
for ($x = 0.01; $x <= 0.99; $x = $x + 0.01) {?>

<option value="<?php echo $x;?>"><?php echo $x;?></option>
   <?php
  } ?>
```

You can define the incremental value as shown above

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

for ($x = 0.01; $x <= 0.99; $x++0.1)